# Triggering download of file from server folder on click button or hyperlink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webforms

In a ASP.NET webform i have to show a link or a button which should be visible or not visible based on whether a pdf file is present in a folder on the server or not. On click of the link or the button, the download of the file from the folder on the server should be triggered. The code has to be implemented through rest service call from javascript. Can someone help me, on how to do this?

I am able to read the file and return the file to the javascript code but how do i trigger the download from there.

Answer (score 0):

In **Asp.Net** you can use

```
<asp:Repeater>
```

Using `<asp:Repeater>` you can create download button but you have to use

`'<%# Eval("PDF_Path_Column_Name") %>'` inside the asp repeater.
Eval is used to bind to an UI item that is setup to be read-only.

**Example :**

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Repeater id="pdfDownload" runat="server"> <a id="PDF" runat="server" href="<%# Eval("PDF_Path_Column_Name") %>"> Download PDF<a/></asp:Repeater>
```

**C# for bind repeater:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
if (!this.IsPostBack)
{
    this.PdfDownlaoder();
}}

private void PdfDownlaoder(){
string connectionString= ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command= new SqlCommand("SELECT  PDF_Path_Column_Name FROM TAble_Name where userId=Session["userID"]", connection ))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
        {
            DataTable data= new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            pdfDownload.DataSource = data;
            pdfDownload.DataBind();
        }
    }
}}
```

Using this method you can easily create download pdf button

But you want implement through javascript.
So you can use Ajax Call for download the PDF and if you want to download different PDF so that you have to pass a unique id .

Comment: but how do i give the path of the file present in the folder on the server in javascript. The path i have given doesn't work. It throws the below error         "Not allowed to load local resource". I have given the path using escape sequence

Comment: i have modified my question. can you help according to the new requirements

Comment: Just wait  give me some time to make another snippet.

Comment: Which control you are using <a>or <button> can you show me the code.

Comment: i am using <a>. The file is present in a folder on the server. But when i am directly giving the folder path in the href it is throwing an error - "Not allowed to load local resource". So i have to read the files content in the backend and pass that information to the front end and trigger the download.

Answer (score 0):

```
As per you requirement this code will helps you.
```

**HTML:**

```
<html>
 <head>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#pdf").hide();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/Check_Pdf",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: "{}",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                debugger
                if (result.d != "n") {
                    $("#pdf").show();
                    $('#pdf').attr('href', result.d);
                }
                else {
                    $("#pdf").hide();
                    alert('No PDF FOUND')
                }
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert("Error try again");
            }
        });


    });
</script>
```

```
   <body>
   <a id="pdf"  runat ="server" target="_blank" >Download Pdf</a> 

</body></html>
```

**C#**

```
     [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static string Check_Pdf ()
    {
        string mainDirectoryPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Your_PDF_Folder/");
        var result = string.Empty;
        var path = string.Empty;
        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(mainDirectoryPath, "*.pdf");
         if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(mainDirectoryPath))
        {          
            foreach (var item in files)
            {
                var file = Path.GetFileName(item);
                path = ("/Your_PDF_Folder/" + file);  
            }
            if (path != string.Empty)
            {
                result = path;
              }
            else
            {               
                result= "n";
            }
        }
       return result;
    }
```